# UniqueValueRenderer with graphicsLayer

Tags: arcgis-js-api

graphicsLayer has a method: [setRenderer(renderer)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#setrenderer)

How can I set certain graphic elements of graphicsLayer using UniqueValueRenderer?
Did not find anything like this on Google therefore opened this issue here.

Any example available?

Using: **js arcgis 3.23**

Is this actually supported in **js arcgis version 3.x**?

As far as I know [it is not supported in **js arcgis version 4.x**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281189/121508)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a solution on the web so I had no choice but to investigate it on my own.
The main question was: how to talk to each graphic element that belongs to a certain graphicsLayer using UniqueValueRenderer.
Could not figure out from the ESRI js arcgis 3.23 API and examples what could be the right interface and syntax to use.
After experimenting a lot with the code came to the following conclusions:

1. Symbols defined at the Graphic layer always override symbols
   defined in a renderer. Therefore I instanced each Graphic using **no**
   Symbol.
2. In order to communicate with each Graphic separately UniqueValueRenderer needs to find some attribute on each Graphic therefore I added an attribute to each Graphic.
3. Now I attempted to use the Graphic attribute **name** in the UniqueValueRenderer while using Graphic attribute **value** to let UniqueValueRenderer select custom symbol for each Graphic.
4. The syntax for UniqueValueRenderer integration with graphicsLayer was not clear from the available documentation and ESRI examples but I experimented with various options and possibilities intuitively and I managed to make it work!

You can see the solution in the attached **code snippet**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Renderer</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/esri/css/esri.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/"></script>
  <script>
    var map;

    require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/renderers/Renderer",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/Color",
        "esri/SpatialReference",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
      function(Map, Renderer, SimpleRenderer, UniqueValueRenderer, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Point, Color, SpatialReference, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleMarkerSymbol, PictureMarkerSymbol, InfoTemplate) {

        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [34.9891877, 31.712805039],
          zoom: 13,
          logo: false
        });

        var locationGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        var symbol1 = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().
        setOffset(0, 0).
        setColor([0, 255, 55, 0.33]).
        setSize(40).
        setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_PATH).
        setPath("M16,3.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.143,7.5,18.121,7.5,18.121S23.5,15.143,23.5,11C23.5,6.858,20.143,3.5,16,3.5z M16,14.584c-1.979,0-3.584-1.604-3.584-3.584S14.021,7.416,16,7.416S19.584,9.021,19.584,11S17.979,14.584,16,14.584z");
        var symbol2 = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().
        setOffset(0, 0).
        setColor([55, 0, 255, 0.33]).
        setSize(40).
        setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_PATH).
        setPath("M16,3.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.143,7.5,18.121,7.5,18.121S23.5,15.143,23.5,11C23.5,6.858,20.143,3.5,16,3.5z M16,14.584c-1.979,0-3.584-1.604-3.584-3.584S14.021,7.416,16,7.416S19.584,9.021,19.584,11S17.979,14.584,16,14.584z");
        var symbol3 = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().
        setOffset(0, 0).
        setColor([255, 0, 55, 0.33]).
        setSize(40).
        setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_PATH).
        setPath("M16,3.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.143,7.5,18.121,7.5,18.121S23.5,15.143,23.5,11C23.5,6.858,20.143,3.5,16,3.5z M16,14.584c-1.979,0-3.584-1.604-3.584-3.584S14.021,7.416,16,7.416S19.584,9.021,19.584,11S17.979,14.584,16,14.584z");

        var attr1 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 1
        };
        var attr2 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 2
        };
        var attr3 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 3
        };
        var attr4 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 4
        };
        var attr5 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 5
        };
        var attr6 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 6
        };
        var attr7 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 7
        };
        var attr8 = {
          "MY_VALUE": 8
        };

        var point1 = new Point(34.9891417, 31.712785039);
        var point2 = new Point(34.9863217, 31.712911039);
        var point3 = new Point(34.95059216533203, 31.740442520689456);
        var point4 = new Point(34.958138448443606, 31.719220882963626);
        var point5 = new Point(34.993487748107846, 31.728375175600405);
        var point6 = new Point(34.990054520568776, 31.73875923932111);
        var point7 = new Point(34.978845102038576, 31.732417351316897);
        var point8 = new Point(34.974815102038576, 31.735412351316897);

        var graphic1 = new Graphic(point1);
        var graphic2 = new Graphic(point2);
        var graphic3 = new Graphic(point3);
        var graphic4 = new Graphic(point4);
        var graphic5 = new Graphic(point5);
        var graphic6 = new Graphic(point6);
        var graphic7 = new Graphic(point7);
        var graphic8 = new Graphic(point8);

        graphic1.setAttributes(attr1);
        graphic2.setAttributes(attr2);
        graphic3.setAttributes(attr3);
        graphic4.setAttributes(attr4);
        graphic5.setAttributes(attr5);
        graphic6.setAttributes(attr6);
        graphic7.setAttributes(attr7);
        graphic8.setAttributes(attr8);

        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic1);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic2);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic3);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic4);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic5);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic6);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic7);
        locationGraphicsLayer.add(graphic8);

        renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(symbol2, "MY_VALUE");
        renderer.addValue({
          value: "6",
          symbol: symbol1
        });
        renderer.addValue({
          value: "3",
          symbol: symbol3
        });

        locationGraphicsLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
        map.addLayer(locationGraphicsLayer);

      });
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body class="tundra">
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```